# How can i connect my Android app to google drive?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api

I have to store large amounts of data(audio and video) in my app. Adding them to the mysql database will not be efficient. Is there a way i can upload it to my google drive and then access it by streaming on my app?
If there is a video tutorial please guide me a link, I'm a beginner at developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code : [Quickstart application showing the Google Drive API for Android](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)

The code is too big to be put up here. Its an easy process.

How to do it?

1. Create an OAuth 2.0 client as described in the Getting Started guide.
2. Make sure you have Google Play Services development set up correctly.
3. Grab the source and create a project in your IDE
4. Run and edit!

Also Refer : [Introduction to the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)